# How to use a php variable in html a href code?

Tags: php, html

I have a variable named $previousStep which I want to incorporate into my html a href link.

```
$previousStep=$myStep-1;
?>
<A HREF="http://localhost/hello.php?step='$previousStep'"><IMG BORDER="0" IMG STYLE  = "position:absolute; LEFT:400px; WIDTH:70px; HEIGHT:70px"    SRC="IMG_8854.jpg"></A>
<?php
```

How would I add this variable in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<? echo $previousStep; ?>` for output PHP data.

```
<a href="http://localhost/action?step=<?php echo $previousStep; ?>">Link</a>
```